# TwitteR lookupUsers() Error in curl

Tags: r

I am getting this error below when trying to get a larger volume of data with the lookupUsers() function.

```
user_info<-lookupUsers(users)

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Everything worked fine when only extracting 10 users or less. I think the problem is the volume. I tried extracting 100 users or more. The same error returned.

I did google around and found nothing specific to this error I am having with TwitteR. Appreciate your help.